# Having trouble receiving data from api

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am new to working with REACT and I am having trouble receiving data from my api. I am using postman to help me build this project, so I am hoping I used it correctly. The app will show up with my table and pagination but not the information from my selected api. I am thinking I need to have my api as an array but how would I go about making my api into an array to properly show my data? here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash"; //lookup lodash
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

const pageSize = 10;
const Posts = () => {
  const [_posts, set_posts] = useState();
  const [paginatedPosts, setPaginatedPosts] = useState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      set_posts(res.data);
      setPaginatedPosts(_(res.data).slice(0).take(pageSize).value());
    });
  }, []);

  const pageCount = _posts ? Math.ceil(_posts.length / pageSize) : 0;
  if (pageCount === 1) return null;
  const pages = _.range(1, pageCount + 1);

  function pagination(pageNo) {
    setCurrentPage(pageNo);
    const startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize;
    const paginatedPosts = _(_posts).slice(startIndex).take(pageSize).value();
    setPaginatedPosts(paginatedPosts);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!paginatedPosts ? (
        "No data found"
      ) : (
        <Table striped bordered hover className="project--table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Birth Year</th>
              <th>Height</th>
              <th>Mass</th>
              <th>Species</th>
              <th>Home World</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {paginatedPosts.map((_post, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{_post.name}</td>
                <td>{_post.birth_year}</td>
                <td>{_post.height}</td>
                <td>{_post.mass}</td>
                <td>{_post.species}</td>
                <td>{_post.home_world}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      )}
      <nav className="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <ul className="pagination">
          {pages.map((page) => (
            <li
              className={
                page === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item"
              }
            >
              <p className="page-link" onClick={() => pagination(page)}>
                {page}
              </p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;


The api I am using is the starwarsapi
```

Comment: Please elaborate- what is the error you’re facing? What is currently happening vs what do you intend to happen?

Comment: there is no issue with the api. Just tested it in postman and in your application as well. Can you tell me what you want to achieve through lodash?. which lodash method are you looking to implement to the response?

Comment: Also, you don't need to paginate the data on the front end. Every thing is paginated by the response itself. You just need to set the page limit.

Comment: Hello! The error I am facing is that the information from the the API will not show up in the web browser. What is suppose to happen is:
1. open the web browser. (npm start) 
2. Browser  opens with information about star wars characters from the API, in a table. Pagination is under the table (1-10). The pagination will be used to go through all 82 characters from the starwars api. 
What is happening:
1.open the browser.
2. browser shows no information from the API (and no table) and only shows the number 1 for pagination.

Comment: The console error I am getting is:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. This to me says either A. I am not using lodash correctly or B I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you always need to check the response body. In your case it'd be res.data.result to get the list, and it has other properties too, like the total length of records. After fixing that, you'll get the list, but your pagination logic has errors.

An advice is to remove the pagination logic, go step by step, so you can understand better what is happening. For example, the way you're doing your page size will always be 1 because you're not counting the total data length, you're couting the list length. So you'll need to use other properties of your response.data object.

Other point that might be useful about the pagination is that you don't really need to paginate on frontend, the api already has a page parameter (10 records per page, like your example). But if you want to create the pagination, you don't need lodash to do it, search for plain javascript solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The posts resides in results in res.data so
you need to set posts to res.data.results

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      set_posts(res.data.result);

    });
  }, []);
```